# SQL server join tables and pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, pivot

I have two tables with data

**TABLE 1**

```
    ---------------------------------------------------
    | SALEID | SOLDBY | SALEPRICE | MARGIN |   DATE   |
    |  1     |  'aa'  |  10,000   |   10   | 2013-1-1 |
    |  2     |  'bb'  |  25,000   |    5   | 2013-5-1 |
```

**TABLE 2**

```
    ---------------------------------------------------
    | SALEITEMID | SALEID | SALEPRICE | CATEGORY |
    |  1         |  1     |   6,000   | BOOKS    |
    |  2         |  1     |   4,000   | PRINTING |
    |  3         |  2     |   5,000   | BOOKS    |
    |  4         |  2     |   12,000  | PRINTING |
    |  5         |  2     |   8,000   | DVD      |
```

I need a query which will produce

**TAB3**

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SALEID | SOLDBY | SALEPRICE | MARGIN |   DATE   |  BOOKS  | PRINTING | DVD
    |  1     |  'aa'  |  10,000   |   10   | 2013-1-1 |  6,000  |  4,000   | 0
    |  2     |  'bb'  |  25,000   |    5   | 2013-5-1 |  5,000  | 12,000   | 8,000
```

I am pretty new to pivoting and not sure if pivot is way to go for this or not.

Comment: How many categories are there? Is this the full list? Could there be more in the future?

Comment: There are about 7 categories. Wont go above it.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This should work:

```
WITH Sales AS (
   SELECT
      S.SaleID,
      S.SoldBy,
      S.SalePrice,
      S.Margin,
      S.Date,
      I.SalePrice,
      I.Category
   FROM
      dbo.Sale S
      INNER JOIN dbo.SaleItem I
         ON S.SaleID = I.SaleID
)
SELECT *
FROM
   Sales
   PIVOT (Max(SalePrice) FOR Category IN (Books, Printing, DVD)) P
;
```

Or alternately:

```
SELECT
   S.SaleID,
   S.SoldBy,
   S.SalePrice,
   S.Margin,
   S.Date,
   I.Books,
   I.Printing,
   I.DVD
FROM
   dbo.Sale S
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT *
      FROM
         (SELECT SaleID, SalePrice, Category FROM dbo.SaleItem) I
         PIVOT (Max(SalePrice) FOR Category IN (Books, Printing, DVD)) P
   ) I ON S.SaleID = I.SaleID
;
```

These have the same result set and may in fact be treated the same by the query optimizer, but possibly not. The big difference comes into play when you start putting conditions on the `Sale` table—you should test and see which query works better.

*Note: it is crucial when using `PIVOT` that only the columns that should be part of the resulting output are available. This is why the two above queries have extra derived table subqueries `(SELECT ...)` so that only specific columns are exposed. All columns that are available to be seen by `PIVOT` that aren't listed in the pivot expression will implicitly be grouped on and included in the final output. This will likely not be what you want.*

May I suggest, however, that you do the pivoting in the presentation layer? If, for example, you are using SSRS it is quite easy to use a matrix control that will do all the pivoting for you. That is best, because then if you add a new `Category`, you won't have to modify all your SQL code!

There is a way to dynamically find the column names to pivot, but it involves dynamic SQL. I don't really recommend that as the best way, either, though it is possible.

Another way that *could* work would be to preprocess this query—meaning to set a trigger on the `Category` table that rewrites a view to contain all the extant categories that exist. This does solve a lot of the other problems I've mentioned, but again, using the presentation layer is best.

**Note**: If your column names (that were formerly values) have spaces, are numbers or begin with a number, or are otherwise not valid identifiers, you must quote them with square brackets as in `PIVOT (Max(Value) FOR CategoryId IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) P`. Alternately, you can modify the values before they get to the `PIVOT` part of the query to prepend some letters or remove spaces, so that the column list doesn't need escaping. For further reading on this check out the rules for *identifiers* in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks Really helpful ....First Query worked, in forst query Pls add   'I' after  INNER JOIN dbo.SaleItem 
OR
INNER JOIN dbo.SaleItem  I

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you examine whether `Max()` is appropriate--if there could be more than one per SaleID + Category then either `Sum()` might be needed, or some kind of `Row_Number()` precalculation so the values can be on separate rows.