# How to get data from 3 differnet tables where parameter is not same for each table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables containing three types of information about a product. The tables are:

Table_Parent_Group:

[image]

Table_Sub_Group

[image]

Table_Productentry

[image]

I need to run a query that will select all product from `Table_Productentry` where ParId = 1

Comment: Hint: `JOIN`   ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073134/sql-server-join-tables-and-pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your query

```
SELECT tpro.* FROM Table_Productentry tpro 
LEFT JOIN Table_Sub_Group t_sub ON tpro.GrId=t_sub.GrId
LEFT JOIN Table_Parent_Group t_par ON t_par.ParId=t_sub.ParId
WHERE t_par.ParId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table_productentry.product_name
from table_productentry
join table_sub_group
join table_parent_group
on table_sub_group.grid=table_productentry.grid and
on table_sub_group.parId=table_paren_group.parId
where table_parent_group.parid=1
```

i hop this work for you