# How to send multiple select sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sql queries are sent to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as success_total,  SUM(AMOUNT) AS success_Amount 
FROM success_log  WHERE TRANSACTION = 'success' 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) as Fail_total, SUM(AMOUNT) AS Fail_Amount 
FROM success_log  WHERE TRANSACTION = 'cancel' 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, SUM(ABS(AMOUNT)) AS Total_Amount 
FROM success_log
```

in this result:

[image]

but I want result:

[image]

How do I send a query to get the results I want?

Comment: This is ONE query.

Comment: Select all desired data into multiple variables and then select that variable at the end.

Comment: Try pivot join, please visit- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073134/sql-server-join-tables-and-pivot

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
( SELECT COUNT(*) as success_total,  SUM(AMOUNT) AS success_Amount 
  FROM success_log  WHERE TRANSACTION = 'success' ) t1
CROSS JOIN
( SELECT COUNT(*) as Fail_total, SUM(AMOUNT) AS Fail_Amount 
  FROM success_log  WHERE TRANSACTION = 'cancel' ) t2
CROSS JOIN 
( SELECT COUNT(*) as total, SUM(ABS(AMOUNT)) AS Total_Amount 
  FROM success_log ) t3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TRANSACTION = 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS success_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRANSACTION = 'success' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS success_Amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRANSACTION = 'cancel' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fail_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRANSACTION = 'cancel' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS Fail_Amount,
       COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(ABS(AMOUNT)) AS Total_Amount
FROM success_log;
```

Fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c67eG8snLddicLLWiRSf9N/0

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL` you can do aggregation  :

```
SELECT SUM(transaction = 'success') AS success_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN transaction = 'success' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS success_Amount,
       SUM(transaction = 'cancel') AS Fail_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN transaction = 'cancel' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Fail_Amount,
       COUNT(*) AS total, 
       SUM(ABS(amount)) AS Total_Amount
FROM success_log sl;
```